# Error : Invalid Json Text. When contacting live using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, live

I am trying to develop a simple metro style app using c# and Xaml, which talks to my live account and do some basic file upload/download kind of things. Even I got many code samples online for this. I am using live sdk 5.2 for this, and using win 8 release preview and VS 2012 RC.

The problem is am getting an error:"Inalid Json Text" in the following code snippet

```
LiveConnectClient client=new LiveConnectClient(e.session);

Var operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
```

The second line is the source of error. The `GetAsync` method to be precise. Please guide me if am providing wrong inputs or so.

I have even looked at Readme doc which I got along with the SDK but which couldn't pull me out of this prob.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code where you establish the Session?

Comment: private async void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
             
                var  operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");

Comment: Hi JP, now the problem is solved. Error occurred is because of internet proxy restrictions

Comment: Good to know, because everything in your code looked correct. :)